# Breaking the binding between component and template

Tags: angular

I am just trying to learn Angular and playing with examples I changed the name of the property on the component by adding a silly "z" to the end of it so something like:

```
selectedProductZ : string
```

but I kept the correct and original name in the template, without the silly "Z" at the end so something like:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Product Name 1</label>
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Product Name 2</label>
    <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct"/>
  </div>
```

I also did restart with an `ng serve` command.

So I was **expecting** this to break and **stop updating because** I had changed the name of property on the component **BUT WHY** is this still working? so this `selectedProduct` in the template had nothing to do with the one in component to begin with?

Comment: After you added the Z on the end, did you save the changes? Can you reproduce this in a stackblitz?

Comment: Once you have added the z, what did you do, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? "still working" is a too vague description. JavaScript is a dynamic language, so you can dynnamically add a property on an object.

Comment: I will double check and try again .. so at least I learned it right? that thing is coming/shoud be coming from component ?

Comment: use ng build --prod. check it's showing error or not.
Sometime ng serve not detect html file error.

Comment: are you using VS code?

Comment: WebStrom........

Comment: did you try restarting it? select File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: It will stop working on the build, try to build it and you will get an error that selectedProduct doesn't exists on the Component

Answer (score -1):

[(ngModel)]--> is doing two way data binding. For example, when we change in input box than the value will changed in   {{selectedProductZ}}.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Product Name 1</label>
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedProductZ"/>
      </div>

    <div>
    {{selectedProductZ}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add some description how and why your code solves the problem. Just adding a snippet doesn't make any sense.